# How to decrypt query string of an url

Tags: decryption, encryption, hash-functions

I need to decrypt the encoded part of query string  i.e.  `Q7eM0euncHNyrhJPjN06lw==` and `sWmYdMUi01BJplzumEaxTw==` from the following urls?

1. `https://XXXX/deed-check/view-deed-summary?encApplicationId=Q7eM0euncHNyrhJPjN06lw==`
2. `https://XXXX/deed-check/view-deed-summary?encApplicationId=sWmYdMUi01BJplzumEaxTw==`

I suspect there is a relation between the content rendered from accessing those urls and above urls.

I have google translated both of the above urls to check if there is any relation.

1. `https://XXXX.translate.goog/deed-check/view-deed-summary?encApplicationId=Q7eM0euncHNyrhJPjN06lw%3D%3D&_x_tr_sl=bn&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en&_x_tr_pto=wapp`
2. `https://XXXX.translate.goog/deed-check/view-deed-summary?encApplicationId=sWmYdMUi01BJplzumEaxTw%3D%3D&_x_tr_sl=bn&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en&_x_tr_pto=wapp`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Equality signs at the end usually means the data is base64 encoded (not necessary encrypted). Have you tried to paste it into a base64 decoder?

Comment: @Robert When I decode using base64 algorithm it looks like `C·ҫ§psr®Oۺ` i.e. gibberish.

Comment: In general it is useless to look at (encrypted) data unless the data structure is obvious or self explaining. The only true chance to decrypt such data is reversing the application that creates or parses such data to learn how the data is structured and processed.